# Order of returned entities in IBM Watson Conversation service

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I want to create a node in the dialog that can detect **airport_from** and **airport_to** from a sentence:

```
"I want to go from Paris Orly to London heathrow"
```

This should give me both values `London Heathrow` and `Paris Orly` as an entity `@airport` using the indexes like this:

```
{
"context": {
"from": "@airport[0]",
"to": "@airport[1]"
},
"output": {
"text": {
  "values": [
    "you are going from @airport[0] to @airport[1]"
  ],
  "selection_policy": "sequential"
}
}
}
```

Typicaly you would have:

```
@airport[0] = 'Paris Orly'
@airport[1] = 'London Heathrow'
```

That works fine, but the problem is when you invert the two airports you get exatly the same result as before (i.e. `@airport[0] = 'Paris Orly'`) and not the inverse.

What I need is getting these entities in the same order as they are in the sentence. Any ideas folks ?

Comment: Have you looked into the full response object? Each entitty has metadata like the location in the input string. It would be possible (in the app) to check that information and assign the context variables based on that.

Comment: @data_henrik I've done that; `[{"entity":"airport","location":[25,28],"value":"Paris Orly","confidence":1},{"entity":"airport","location":[18,21],"value":"London Heathrow","confidence":1},{"entity":"city","location":[2,6],"value":"Nantes","confidence":0.56}]`. Isn't there a way to sort the array of `entities` within a node in the dialog ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [ternary operator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) in the response. It is linked on the [Watson Conversation expression language](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/expression-language.html):

```
<? entities['airport'][0].location[0]<entities['airport'][1].location[0] ? 
'First, then second' : 'Second comes first' ?>
```

The above evaluates the first expression and if `true` uses the expression after the `?`, if `false` the expression after the `:`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it, you'll have to test the location of the entities and create separate answers (as many as you need).: 
[image]

I am still hoping for a better approach.

Comment: This only works if the order always is "from" to "to".

Comment: This is true. I tried another approach which uses regular expression to get the word right after `from` and `to` but it doesn't give me the advantage of using it as an entity...

Comment: I found a better way after looking into the SpEL

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to create 2 entities. "From City" and "To City" and add same values in both like in "From City" add From London ,From Newyork and in "To City" add To London,To Newyork. This is a better way.